# how to display tables under a particular schema in a pSQL session?

Tags: psql

In a pSQL session (linux server), the command \dn displays the schemas in a database. Is there any command that could display tables just under a particular schema, say xyz?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\dt` is used to list tables. By default it will list those in the current schema.

You can, however, pass a pattern to it. In your case, you want to do:

```
\dt xyz.
```

This will list all tables in the `xyz` schema.

Here's some further things you can do with it:

- list all tables in all schemas: `\dt *.`
- list tables with `user` in their name: `\dt *user*`
- list tables with `user` in their name in all schemas: `\dt *.*user*`

Answer (score 0):

The **"\z" COMMAND** use to list of tables when inside the interactive psql session.

```
# psql -d mcdb -U admin -p 5555
mcdb=# \z
```

Comment: it looks like \z displays tables for all the available schemas in mcdb, which could be too many to review. Can I display tables in just one particular schema?